# Bootstrap Modal switching

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have two modals with id1 and id2 and I want to open one of the modal according to the state of paddle switch.When switch is in 'off-state', Modal with id 'id1' needs to opened and when switch is in 'on-state', Modal with id 'id2' needs to opened. Currently on 'onChange' event, I am adding id of modal that needs to be opened to 'data-open' and 'aria-controls' attribute.

```
$('#button-id1').attr('data-open', 'id1');
$('#button-id1').attr('aria-controls', 'id2');
```

But this is working just for first time, when I closed the opened modal, switching the paddle shows the previously opened modal.
Can anyone give me an idea what is going here?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#id1').modal("hide");
```

It should be in the if statement when the switch is on-state selector id of your modal should be the modal you want to hide or remove else is the off-state

```
if(switch_button == on_state){
    $('#id1').modal("show");
    $('#id2').modal("hide");
}else{
    $('#id1').modal("hide");
    $('#id2').modal("show");
}
```

If your confused what condition you have to put. just if the switch button if there is a class open or whatsoever

```
if($('#switch_button').hasClass('open')){}
```

If you dont want to open the modal directly when the switch is changed you can modify it inside the if statement

```
if(switch_button == on_state){
    $('button1 of the first modal').click(function(){
        $('#id1').modal("show");
        $('#id2').modal("hide");
    });
}else{
    $('button2 of the second modal').click(function(){
        $('#id1').modal("hide");
        $('#id2').modal("show");
    });
}
```

And make sure that you modal has a class of modal-lg for large modal-md for medium and modal-sm for small to see that your modal is in different size.

```
<!-- Large Modal Format -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="large" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- Modal Content Here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Medium Modal Format -->

        <div class="modal fade" id="medium" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- Modal Content Here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Small Modal Format -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="small" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <!-- Modal Content Here -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Modal -->
```

Comment: I cannot open modal right away after switch state change, I have another button which opens modal. The problem is button is not always showing modal according to switch state, it is just working for the first time.

Comment: What is the difference of the two modals by the way?

Comment: They are two entirely different modals like one is 'School Form Modal' and another is 'College Form Modal'.